# ajax xmlhttprequests in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, xmlhttprequest

I am a newbie to xmlhttprequests.I am not understanding how the xml api works with nodejs.I can understand express properly about the servers and routes. I would suggest someone explain me the setup of xhr api with nodejs with an example .Just a basic example of how all works is fine.
Thank you!

Comment: From the server's point of view an Ajax call is just another incoming request that you make a route for and you decide what kind of response to send.  Because the response is going back to your Javascript (rather than the browser engine), you have the option of sending a response type such as JSON in order to send easy-to-parse data back to your Javascript.  What part of this process do you not understand?

Comment: So yea ,how to set up the server for the XML api? Like in node we are creating a server and listening at a port .likewise how to set up here ?

Comment: It's just another route on your server.  It looks no different from any other incoming http request from the browser.  You don't need to make a new server for it.  Just define a new route on your existing server and use that path and host in the Ajax request. Also, in today's modern browser you should use the `fetch()` API, not the XMLHttpRequest API.  It's much more modern and straightforward to use.  There are hundreds of examples of this on the web.

Comment: Okay cool thanks! Do we have to define routes in node??

Comment: You can use many languages and many environments to implement a web server.  nodejs is one option.  If you are using nodejs, then you would define a route for your ajax call in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example using the `fetch()` API from the browser:

```
// server
const app = require('express')();
app.get("/getrandom", (req, res) => {
    let random = Math.random();           // generate random number
    res.json({random});                   // wrap random number in an object and send it
});
app.listen(80);
```

And, browser Javascript code:

```
fetch("http://yourhost/getrandom").then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
    console.log(result);     // {random: 0.7594837274}
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This particular example uses the more modern `fetch()` API from the browser.  The server code would not be any different whether you were using the `fetch()` API or the `XMLHttpRequest()` API.  In both cases, they just generate an http request which your server has a route for and sends a response to.

Since the server here is sending back JSON, `res.json()` is used as part of the `fetch()` call to read the body of the response and parse the JSON into a Javascript object.

Comment: Hey, thank you for this answer. This helped a lot. Can you answer this question also, please ? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62192186/12599438)  This is a question on socket.io       @jfriend00