# socket.io communication between two different client side js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, module, socket.io

I have the following code in file1.html:

```
    <body>
    <button type="button" id="accept" value="accept">Accept</button>
        <script>
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
          // Query DOM
          var acceptButton=document.getElementById('accept');
          // Emit events
          acceptButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

          socket.emit('notification', {
            message: acceptButton.value,

          });
           });

       module.exports=socket;
       </script>
       </body>
```

In file2.html:

```
         <body>
             <div id="notifications">
             <h1>Your notifications here</h1>
           </div>
           <script>
           var socket=require('/file1.html');
           var notification=document.getElementById('notifications');
           socket.on('notification', function(data){
            notification.innerHTML+='<p> the event was accepted<p>';

           });

          </script>  
      </body>
```

Nodejs server code:

```
    var server=app.listen(4000,()=>{
      console.log('listening at port 4000');
     })

     var io=socket(server);
     //connection to socket (backend)

     io.on('connection',function(socket){
     console.log('socket connection made',socket.id);
       socket.on('notification', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('notification', data);
      });
       });
```

I am a newbie to socket.io .I want to send the data from file1.html and receive data from file2.html. I don't think there is any mistake in the server code. I am doubtful only in the html files. How do I solve it?

Comment: does the emit reach the server?

Comment: Yes it reaches the server!

Comment: then try it with `io.emit('notification', data);`

Comment: Where should I use this ? Can you explain it with the answer?

Comment: Is the require method in <script> tag of file2.html correct ?

Comment: on the server side instead of `io.sockets.emit('notification', data);` try `io.emit('notification', data);`

Comment: on the client side you can import socket io with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: No. I am getting an error like 'reference error : require is not defined ' .So the error is with file2.html. I need to receive data from the server in file2.html

Comment: also we usually use `require()` ONLY on node.js

Comment: How do we do it? Can you explain briefly? And yes it is a script tag inside html file .So I am little bit confused.

Comment: can you please answer this question?